# Meteor.userId() not reactive in a react component?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I just implemented a small authentification system to my current project using the
 `accounts-password` package. The authentification itself is working properly.

In my view, there are some buttons and stuff which should be only displayed to logged in users. I got this working by checking `Meteor.userId()`. If `null`, the buttons won't be displayed.

The problem is the following:
When I'm logging in (or out), my view doesn't rerender. It's simply not hiding or showing the buttons which shall be toggled. It always takes an independent rerender to show or hide them.

The [Meteor-Documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#current-user) states, that `Meteor.userId()` shall be reactive but it's not behaving that way in my component.

Here's some react-component showing how my view looks like showing or hiding buttons depending on `Meteor.userId()`:

```
class SomeReactComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        ...
    }

    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <span>
                <p>Text that should be displayed to anyone!</p>
                { Meteor.userId() ? (
                    <button id="btn">
                        This button is only available to logged in users
                    </button>
                ) : ""}
            </span>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `createContainer`, this will make your `Meteor.userId()` reactive.
to install just type:

> meteor npm install --save react-addons-pure-render-mixin
>
> meteor add react-meteor-data

```
import React from "react";
import {createContainer} from "meteor/react-meteor-data";

class SomeReactComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
    }

   

    render() {
        return (
            <span>
                <p>Text that should be displayed to anyone!</p>
                { this.props.authenticated ? (
                    <button id="btn">
                        This button is only available to logged in users
                    </button>
                ) : ""}
            </span>
        );
    }
}
export default createContainer(()=>{
  return {
    authenticated: Meteor.userId(),
  }
},SomeReactComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion! The reason I have to do this is that meteor reactivity does not equal react reactivity. So I have to wrap the meteor reactivity using `createContainer()` in order to have a react reactive ui :) Thanks again!

Comment: yes, by wrapping our component to container using createContainer it will make our data reactive.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an easy way to do that:

1. Add `import {useTracker} from "meteor/react-meteor-data";`
2. const user = useTracker(() => {
   return Meteor.userId()
   });

Full Example :

```
import {useTracker} from "meteor/react-meteor-data";

    export default function App() {
        const user = useTracker(() => {
            return Meteor.userId()
        });
        if (!user) {
            return (
                    <Global_Router Client={null} About={About} HomeNavbar={HomePageNav} HomePage_Home={HomePage_Home}
                                   HomeFooter={Footer} Homepage_Contacts={Homepage_Contacts}/>
            );
        }
        else {
            return(
                <RouterClient/>
    
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer worth looking in to is the trackerReact package at
https://github.com/ultimatejs/tracker-react

Using this should make the component be reactive, just as you'd expect it to be.

```
class SomeReactComponent extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {
```